Plotting Central Tendencies (Mean, Median, Mode) into Seaborn Subplots
I Have an error when I try to run this code
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable

import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
sns.set_theme()
sns.set_style('white')

df_train = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/lokalhangatt/stackoverlow/raw/refs/heads/main/train.csv')

df_train = df_train.dropna(axis=1)

null_info = df_train.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index().head(20)
null_info.columns = ["Variable", "NullValue"]

list_soal = ['SalePrice', 'GrLivArea', 'GarageArea']

# fig,ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=True, figsize=(14,4))
def function1(ax):
    ax[1].set_title('Histogram for Non-Transfomed Data', fontsize=16)
    for i in range(len(list_soal)):
        sns.histplot(df_train[list_soal[i]], kde=False, stat='density', bins = 30, ax=ax[i])
        sns.kdeplot(df_train[list_soal[i]], ax=ax[i])
    for j in range (len(list_soal)):
        line1 = plt.axvline(df_train[list_soal].mean(), color="k", linestyle="--", label = "mean")
        line2 = plt.axvline(np.median(df_train[list_soal]), color="r", linestyle="--", label = "median")
        first_legend = plt.legend(handles=[line1,line2], loc=1)

# fig,ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=True, figsize=(14,4))
def function2(ax):
    ax[1].set_title('Histogram for Transfomed Data', fontsize=16)
    for i in range(len(list_soal)):
        sns.histplot(np.log10(df_train[list_soal[i]]), kde=False, stat='density', bins = 30, ax=ax[i])
        sns.kdeplot(np.log10(df_train[list_soal[i]]), ax=ax[i])

fig,ax = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(14,9), sharey='row')
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4)


function1(ax[0])
function2(ax[1])

plt.show()

I want to plot central tendencies on every subplot I run. Here's my Subplots:

It should show the central tendency of every box on subplots. But when I try to run that code above, I get an error that says:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_4812\2093474016.py in ?()
     40 fig,ax = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(14,9), sharey='row')
     41 fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4)
     42 
     43 
---> 44 function1(ax[0])
     45 function2(ax[1])
     46 
     47 plt.show()

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_4812\2093474016.py in ?(ax)
     25     for i in range(len(list_soal)):
     26         sns.histplot(df_train[list_soal[i]], kde=False, stat='density', bins = 30, ax=ax[i])
     27         sns.kdeplot(df_train[list_soal[i]], ax=ax[i])
     28     for j in range (len(list_soal)):
---> 29         line1 = plt.axvline(df_train[list_soal].mean(), color="k", linestyle="--", label = "mean")
     30         line2 = plt.axvline(np.median(df_train[list_soal]), color="r", linestyle="--", label = "median")
     31         first_legend = plt.legend(handles=[line1,line2], loc=1)

c:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in ?(x, ymin, ymax, **kwargs)
   2423 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.axvline)
   2424 def axvline(x=0, ymin=0, ymax=1, **kwargs):
-> 2425     return gca().axvline(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, **kwargs)

c:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in ?(self, x, ymin, ymax, **kwargs)
    833         xmin, xmax = self.get_xbound()
    834 
    835         # Strip away the units for comparison with non-unitized bounds.
    836         xx, = self._process_unit_info([("x", x)], kwargs)
--> 837         scalex = (xx < xmin) or (xx > xmax)
    838 
    839         trans = self.get_xaxis_transform(which='grid')
    840         l = mlines.Line2D([x, x], [ymin, ymax], transform=trans, **kwargs)

c:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in ?(self)
   1464     @final
   1465     def __nonzero__(self) -> NoReturn:
-> 1466         raise ValueError(
   1467             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1468             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1469         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How can I show these central tendencies on every subplots?

Could you add the full error trace? With just telling the error, without context, without knowing which line provoke it, you're making it hard for people to try to help you.  Also, when you encounter an error, it is helpful to NOT turn any warnings off. Further, as you are working with subplots, plt.axvline() and plt.legend() should be replaced by ax[i].axvline() and ax[i].legend(). The plt functions only act on the "current" subplot (usually the last one created). Also, as you first subplot is empty, some functions might not work on empty data.

@JohanC I'm sorry, Here's the error trace I've got.

You are getting a pandas error on this line: plt.axvline(df_train[list_soal].mean(), ...). You need to check whether df_train[list_soal] isn't empty. If that doesn't help, you can try print(df_train[list_soal]) to see what's in there. Did you read my comment about the additional problem you have by incorrectly using plt.axvline() instead of ax[i].axvline()?

@JohanC Ah, I got it. Thank you sir
